# Windows 7 Defrag scheduled seems did not work

Tags: windows-7, defragment, task-scheduler

I use windows 7 from the beginning, so the first time when I looked into the Windows 7 Disk Defragment program and I saw the Scheduled Defrag I supposed that it worked and I did not check if it worked good...

More and more months later I had some problems running programs/games/etc and I come back there and I saw in the bottom that Last Run wasn't updated at all...
So 1 month ago I manually did a defrag an all the disks re-scheduled the automatic deframentation to 1PM (the computer is always on at that time)...

But it seems to me that it never do a defragmentation.... 
Look at the below image..

Is this normal to not have the last run updated?

[image]

**UPDATE**
After 2 Month I looked again into disk Defrag...
Here's some screenshots

Defrag option
[image]

Task Scheduler:
[image]

The % of fragmentation on main and secondary disk is 6% and 5%, the Last Run is today becasue I started the analyze disk, but before that Last Run was the same as the System Reserved disk and the first screenshot (03/20/2012)
As you can see from the last screen, the scheduler never started...
Now I changed some conditions like remove the `start service only if idle for 3minutes`
Hope this helps, otherwise any other guess?

Comment: If the drive is not fragmented, it may choose not to run on schedule. They all show 0% fragmentation. I run mine manually from the command prompt once a month since I do not have a consistent time my PC will be left on when I am not using it.

Comment: I got a 30% fragmentation last month...

Comment: Change the time it is scheduled to run, maybe something else is scheduled at the same time, does the PC go to sleep or hibernate?

Comment: It's not the time... before it was on 2AM on wendsday, not is 1PM every day... the computer is not in sleep or hibernate and there are no other task scheduled for that time...

Comment: See if there is anything helpful here...http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/128176-Scheduled-Disk-defrag-does-not-run

Comment: Check event viewer to see if it logs any error messages for defrag, also see this...http://www.thewindowsclub.com/troubleshooting-windows-disk-defragmenter-utility

Comment: If you click on 'Configure Schedule' and 'Select Disks' , are your hard disks actually selected to be defraged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem removing all the condition for starting/stopping the process...

Go to:
`Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler`

Then:
`Task Scheduler (Local) -> Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Defrag`
Right click on the first item and `Properties`

And I unchecked everything

[image]

Hope this helps someone :)